# Sass source maps not auto-refreshing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Canary (Version 30.0.1570.0 canary) I've set up sass source maps as follows:

1. DevTools > Settings > General > Enable CSS source maps + Auto-reload generated CSS   CHECKED!
2. DevTools > Settings > Added folder `public`

My folder structure looks as follows:

```
public
  sass
    _buttons.scss
    style.scss
  css
    style.css
  index.html  (with link href=css/style.css)
```

In DevTools I can do `inspect element` and see that a style-rule comes from _buttons.scss. I can click the _buttons.scss and get the DevTools to display the scss source. I can modify the source in devtools and hit cmd+s and it's saved to disk and when switching to sublime, the file has been updated. BUT in Chrome the css is not automatically reloaded. I have to refresh the page manually to reload the css.

Sass version:

```
$ sass -v
$ Sass 3.3.0.alpha.149 (Bleeding Edge)
```

I watch with:

```
$ sass --scss --sourcemap --watch public/sass:public/css
```

Any body else having problems with the `Auto-reload generated CSS` in Chrome (Canary) ?
I've also tried Chrome "normal" (20.0...) and same problem there, no auto-reload.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same exact issue. You could try http://tin.cr/ which auto-reloads when you save in devtools.

Comment: Nope, cannot get tin.cr to work on either Chrome or Canary. Nothing is autoreloading. Tried with file://...index.html and http://....index.html and tried with sass as well as normal css. Did you get your workflow to work with tin.cr @alpacalips? And are there really not more people with these problems?

Comment: Is there some way to manually tell chrome to reload it's css's?

Comment: Are you using a workspace with network resources mapped to local resources?

Comment: If yes, there's a known issue, which prevents this feature from working properly when the scss files' URLs computed from the URLs found in source maps contain "../" directories. As a workaround, you might try having sass/ as a subdirectory of you css/ directory and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Cotten I wasn't able to get it working with tincr either. I was hoping maybe you would have success so I'd know wether or not it was user error on my part. At this point, I'm waiting to test it out when a new version of chrome is released.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov that was the issue for me. Removed the "../" in the source map and it worked.

Comment: Anyone has any solution on this one? I have the exact same problem as well. Is it a directory path problem? How should I set up my folders so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Workspaces? That's what I use and it's working fine for me, and always has. A bunch of things have moved out of experiments recently, so maybe that's why it's not working?